# Erro nas dependencias

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, sdk, dependências

Olá, estou começando a desenvolver uma aplicação web com .Net CORE.
tenho instalado o .Net Core SDK 2.2.103 e quando eu abro o meu projeto, tenho alguns erros nas dependencias, como é mostrado a seguir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Este é o meu código do projeto de pacotes:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
  </PropertyGroup>


  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.2.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
  </ItemGroup>


  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Alguem pode me dar uma ajuda nisso ai ?

EDIT 1:
Ao tentar buildar, aparecem os seguintes erros:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Abre o Package Manager Console e executa o comando dotnet restore, vê o que acontece.

Comment: É só buildar o projeto.

Comment: Ia falar isso agora, acredito que um build solution resolva

Comment: Olá, eu fiz o que vcs disseram e quando eu fiz o dotnet restore, ele sumiu o erro do ultimo arquivo, mas continua nos outros

Comment: e eu nao estou conseguindo buildar, sempre da um erro:
"error : Found invalid data while decoding."

Answer (score 0):

1. Crie um arquivo chamado: global.json.
2. Inclua na raiz do projeto (mesmo nível da soluction).
3. Adicione o arquivo na soluction.
4. Clique com botão direito na soluction-> Add -> Existing Item -> global.json

> Conteúdo do global.json

{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "2.2.103"
  }
}

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]